# Remove first name/value of each object in an array

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
my_json = [
    {
        "DontNeed":"Remove",
        "year":"2015",
        "Some name": "some value"

    },
    {
        "DontNeed":"Remove",
        "year":"2016",
        "Some name": "another value"
    },
];
```

I want to have that JSON like this:

```
new_json = [
    {
        "year":"2015",
        "Some name": "some value"

    },
    {
        "year":"2016",
        "Some name": "another value"
    },
];
```

Is there a way to do this? an known function?

Comment: You say you want to remove the `first` name/value. Objects are not ordered, so it's not clear what you mean. Will the value you want to remove always have a specific key?

Comment: Yes, in this case "DontNeed"

Comment: *my_json* is not JSON, consider `arr.forEach(obj => delete obj.DontNeed)`.

Comment: JSON and JavaScript objects/arrays are two different things.

Comment: @pmirnd Please give us feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delete operator to remove a known key (in this case property) from an object. Combined with the `map` function you can quickly remove the property from all entries.

```js
var my_json = [
    {
        "DontNeed":"Remove",
        "year":"2015",
        "Some name": "some value"

    },
    {
        "DontNeed":"Remove",
        "year":"2016",
        "Some name": "another value"
    },
];
var expected = my_json.map(j => {
  delete j['DontNeed']
  return j;
});
console.log(expected);
```

### Edit

As @Mark Meyer mentioned in the comments this will remove the prop/value from `my_json` as well. If you want to preserve the original see his answer. Just in case that answer goes away for whatever reason: `new_json = my_json.map(({DontNeed, ...rest}) => rest);`. However, if this answer were to be accept his should be accepted.

Comment: This has the side effect of deleting the property from the original object as well.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged the question with `javascript`, so I'm assuming that you're looking for a JavaScript solution to this problem.

Presuming that your JSON is in an object of some kind (which I thought was called `my_json`), you can simply do something like:

```
for (var x in my_json) {
    delete x['DontNeed'];
}
```

Comment: I think the issues with using *for..in* with Arrays have been well documented, see [*Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea). You can use *forEach* to do the same thing safely.

Comment: Hence _you can simply do something like:_ instead of _you must do this:_. However, the point is well made; I wrote the code on the fly and in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother having more properties, leave it as it is.

If you really can't, then use `Array.map` function like this:

```js
my_json = [
    { "DontNeed":"Remove", "year":"2015", "Some name": "some value" },
    { "DontNeed":"Remove", "year":"2016", "Some name": "another value" }
];

new_json = my_json.map(x => ({
    year: x.year,
    'Some name': x['Some name']
}));

console.log(new_json);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure off the property (or properties) you don't want and make a new array with `map()`:

```js
let my_json = [
    {"DontNeed":"Remove","year":"2015","Some name": "some value"},
    {"DontNeed":"Remove","year":"2016","Some name": "another value"}
];

let new_json = my_json.map(({DontNeed, ...rest}) => rest)
console.log(new_json)
```